# CDI Produces Method InjectionPoint is Null

Tags: java, junit, cdi

I am leaning CDI Annotation have a question with respect to Produces Annotation:

I have a Bank

```
public interface Bank {
    public void withdrawal();
    public void deposit();
}
```

Two Implementation flavors

```
public class BankOfAmerica implements Bank {
    public void withdrawal() {
        System.out.println("You are withdrawing from Bank Of America");
    }

    public void deposit() {
        System.out.println("You are depositing in Bank Of America");
    }
}

public class Chase implements Bank {
    public void withdrawal() {
        System.out.println("You are withdrawing from Chase");
    }

    public void deposit() {
        System.out.println("You are depositing in Chase");
    }
}
```

A Qualifier

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
public @interface BankProducer {
}
```

An Enum

```
public enum BankName {
    DCU(DCU.class), Chase(Chase.class), BankOfAmerica(BankOfAmerica.class);

    private Class<? extends Bank> bankType;

    private BankName(Class<? extends Bank> bankType) {
        this.bankType = bankType;
    }

    public Class<? extends Bank> getBankType() {
        return bankType;
    }
}
```

An Annotation to bind the BankName

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
public @interface BankType {
    @Nonbinding
    BankName value();
}
```

A Factory

```
public class BankFactory {
    @Produces
    @BankProducer
    public Bank createBank(@Any Instance<Bank> instance, InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        Annotated annotated = injectionPoint.getAnnotated();
        BankType bankTypeAnnotation = annotated.getAnnotation(BankType.class);
        Class<? extends Bank> bankType = bankTypeAnnotation.value().getBankType();
        return instance.select(bankType).get();
    }
}
```

And a JUnit

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ProducesTest {
    @Inject
    @BankProducer
    @BankType(BankName.BankOfAmerica)
    private Bank bankOfAmerica;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addPackages(true, "com.tutorial.produces")
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml").merge(getDependecies());
    }

    private static JavaArchive getDependecies() {
        JavaArchive[] javaArchives = Maven.configureResolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
            .resolve("org.projectlombok:lombok").withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
        JavaArchive mergedLibraries = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class);
        for (JavaArchive javaArchive : javaArchives) {
            mergedLibraries.merge(javaArchive);
        }
        return mergedLibraries;
    }

    @Test
    public void create() {
        assertEquals(banks.getBankOfAmerica().getClass(), BankOfAmerica.class);
    }
}
```

POM - using tomee

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0-1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am getting a NullPointer exception in my factory createBank method. InjectionPoint is Null. What is the issue and how do I resolve it?

Alternate Solution: Tried Weld

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

JUnit

```
@RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class)
public class ProducesWeldTest {
    @Inject
    @BankProducer
    @BankType(BankName.BankOfAmerica)
    private Bank bankOfAmerica;

    @Test
    public void create() {
         assertEquals(bankOfAmerica.getClass(), BankOfAmerica.class);
    }
}
```

WeldContext and WeldJUnit4Runner are from here - 
http://memorynotfound.com/java-se-unit-testing-cdi-junit-jboss-weld-se/

Comment: The qualifiers for the injection point and the producer point must match. And you are doing a mistake of having two qualifiers, one for producer and one for injection. It should be one.

Comment: I just tested your implementation using Weld  and everything works fine. I guess your problem lies in your unit test. I don't have experience with Arquillian to tell whether it is capable of initializing and injecting beans.

Comment: I updated the post with my POM. I am using TOMEE

Comment: ujulu - I have not tried WELD.

Comment: maress - I do not have two qualifiers. I have only one 'BankProducer'. The other annotation is to provide the class, that I need to instantiate in createBank method

Comment: It worked with WELD (2.2.8.Final). No change. Updated the Weld test in the post. Still don't know why tomee arquillian did not work?

Comment: your setup is a little weird.  Do you purposely have two annotations?  You're better off having 1 annotation that encapsulates both.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment to the post, the CDI implememtatin seems to work. I think the problem lies in the test. Originally, I just wrote a simple test with a `main()` method and everything works. Now I moved the same code to the JUnit test and it still works. To test your implementation I just added the following client for your factory and a test class as follows:

```
public class BankClient {

    @Inject
    @BankProducer
    @BankType(BankName.BankOfAmerica)
    private Bank bankOfAmerica;

    public void deposit() {
        bankOfAmerica.deposit();
    }

    public void withdrawal() {
        bankOfAmerica.withdrawal();
    }
}
```

// JUnit test

```
public class BankServiceTest {
    private static Weld weld = new Weld();

    private static BankClient sut;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initWeld() {
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();;
        sut = container.instance().select(BankClient.class).get();
    }


    @Test
    public void deposit_should_be_invoked() {
        sut.deposit();
    }

    @Test
    public void withdrawal_should_be_called() {
        sut.withdrawal();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutDown() {
        weld.shutdown();
    }
}
```

After executing the test, you should see the following output on the console and JUnit green bar:

> You are depositing in Bank Of America
>
> You are withdrawing from Bank Of America

Comment: Thanks all for the helping me out.